# Cybersource undefined function cybs_load_config()

Tags: php

I went through documentation of cybersource api to set it up with PHP on linux.

I followed all instructions and added required file to extensions directory and added it in php.ini and rebooted httpd.

Now when i call php file it gives :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function cybs_load_config()
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was my fault. Forgot to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

This is how to set it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/simapin.nn/libfolder:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Resolved it the next day just realized today to post here. Hope this might be of help to someone.