# Fatal error: Call to undefined function cybs_load_config()

Tags: payment-gateway

I was building cybersource payment gateway on my site.

But its not work .

When I run this on my site it show and error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function cybs_load_config()
```

Any body tell me the solution of this.

Comment: what script do you exactly run? add the code of it if you can...

Answer (score 1):

Hello there are having a solution of this

if you seen error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function cybs_load_config()
```

It means yo required "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Then you want to

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/simapin.nn/libfolder:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

It resolved your error.

Comment: sorry for the second answer... the next time google for it a little better, at least search on stackoverflow!! Here is the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483201/cybersource-undefined-function-cybs-load-config)